# android support multiple screen and multiple drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I've made three files with the same name.

96*96 = xhigh :

[image]

72*72 = high :

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/SCmLV.png]

48*48 = medium :

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/oxX0d.png]

when I create an AVD with 480*854(hdpi) picture number three is selected.
why ?

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/7kIlv.jpg]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/1qZwA.jpg]

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ex31"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ex31.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you certain that your emulator is hdpi? What have you specified as the dpi value?

Comment: yes, http://i.stack.imgur.com/zSYHu.jpg

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct png file in hdpi folder? Right click on one.png and choose open.

Comment: yes, http://up.clip2ni.com/i/images/stsrke3x2zv157rqefsp.jpg :(

Comment: That is indeed very odd. The emulator's clock and status icons looks very odd to me as well. Perhaps something's not quite right in your SDK folder, but I really don't know what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your emulator isn't set to the correct DPI. Open the Android Virtual Device Manager and check that `hw.lcd.density` is (roughly) 240. Remember, a DPI of 160 is baseline 1x, or mdpi.

It should look something like this:

[image: Emulator with hdpi]

You should also see the density bin when launching the emulator:

[image: Launching hdpi emulator]